# How to send HTTPS request with Rest Assured using .crt certificate and public .key token

Tags: java, ssl, rest-assured

I need to send https request with REST assured having client **.crt** certificate and public key **.key**
How do I send request if my certificate and key in project like

```
"src/test/resources/certificate.crt"
"src/test/resources/key.key"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String clientCertificatePath = "certs/ClientCertificate.p12";
String trustStorePath = "C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_91/lib/security/cacerts";
String trustStorePassword = "changeit"; // default trust store password

KeyStore clientStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
clientStore.load(new FileInputStream(clientCertificatePath), clientPassword.toCharArray());

KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
kmf.init(clientStore, clientPassword.toCharArray());
KeyManager[] kms = kmf.getKeyManagers();

KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
trustStore.load(new FileInputStream(trustStorePath), trustStorePassword.toCharArray());

TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
tmf.init(trustStore);
TrustManager[] tms = tmf.getTrustManagers();

SSLContext sslContext = null;
sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(kms, tms, new SecureRandom());

SSLSocketFactory lSchemeSocketFactory=null;

lSchemeSocketFactory = new SSLSocketFactory(clientStore, clientPassword, trustStore);

// configure Rest Assured
RestAssured.config = RestAssured.config().sslConfig(sslConfig().with().sslSocketFactory(lSchemeSocketFactory).and().allowAllHostnames());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 String response = RestAssured
        .given()
        .trustStore("src/test/resources/certificate.crt", "paasword")
        .when()
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .header("Authorization", authHeader)
        .baseUri("https://server.us.oracle.com:55898")
        .queryParam("name", args)
        .get("/validendpoint").prettyPrint();
```